# Does an ip catch all exist?

Tags: iptables, ip-blocking, security

I'm trying to block specific ip address traffic using this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.148.10.209 -j DROP
```

Does an ip address catch all exist where I could block all addresses on 192.148.10.* using the above command?

Comment: This is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) as it deals with your persona machine.

Comment: i am not sure if sf is only for work machines. i would say it is more likely people use personal machines to test and experiment even it is for work. i exclusively test things in my personal servers for this kind of activities.

Comment: @JasonWade the are talking about the statement 'Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to **managing computer systems in a professional capacity.**. In that link he shared.  Your question wasn't really that bad, but you really don't need to tell people that you are a noob, or that this is a 'personal' box.  Don't share the computers 'life story', just get to the problem.

Comment: agreed. thanks a lot for the clarification. sorry i may not have been clear. also i think i understand the spirit of that statement and the usage is for professional capacity but the equipment could still be personal. hope i do not confuse anyone even more :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, use cidr notation in iptables

192.148.10.0/24